# Parsing IP Adresses from a .TXT file on Python

Tags: python, parsing, slice

So I am trying to take all the IP addresses from a .txt and have them print out in a new text file, one per line on Python

The text looks like this

```
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1  
  2    47 ms    14 ms    27 ms  cpe-67-254-0-1.nycap.res.rr.com [67.254.0.1]  
  3    30 ms    29 ms    21 ms  g3-27.glvlny09-rtr001.albany.rr.com  [24.29.45.249]  
  4    26 ms    12 ms    11 ms  24.58.33.254  
  5    19 ms    19 ms    19 ms  be26.rochnyei01r.northeast.rr.com [24.58.32.52]  
  6    33 ms    35 ms    35 ms  bu-ether45.chcgildt87w-bcr00.tbone.rr.com [107.14.19.106]  
  7    31 ms    30 ms    31 ms  0.ae1.pr1.chi10.tbone.rr.com [107.14.17.194]  
  8    32 ms    30 ms    44 ms  216.1.94.65  
  9    39 ms    38 ms    40 ms  207.88.13.128.ptr.us.xo.net [207.88.13.128]  
 10    38 ms    43 ms    37 ms  207.88.12.167.ptr.us.xo.net [207.88.12.167]  
 11    36 ms    39 ms    37 ms  207.88.14.181.ptr.us.xo.net [207.88.14.181]  
 12   176 ms   153 ms   147 ms  209.48.42.54  
 13    43 ms    43 ms    43 ms  216.239.46.248  
 14    43 ms    44 ms    46 ms  72.14.236.98  
 15    51 ms    48 ms    50 ms  72.14.232.73  
 16    60 ms    60 ms    58 ms  216.239.47.39  
 17    67 ms    75 ms    69 ms  216.239.59.82  
 18   100 ms    97 ms    98 ms  216.239.41.138  
 19    99 ms    98 ms   100 ms  64.233.174.191  
 20   101 ms   100 ms    99 ms  209.85.241.73  
 21   100 ms    98 ms    99 ms  lax17s04-in-f14.1e100.net [216.58.219.46]
```

I was told to use splicing, but I;ve written some code about 4 times and nothing seems to work, similar questions are on here but I can't get them to work

Any sense of direction would help!

this is what I have so far

```
file = open('ipaddr.txt', 'r')
        ips = []
        for text in file.readlines():
            text = text.rstrip()
            found = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})',text)
            if regex:
                ips.extend(found)
```

Comment: Post your code please...

Comment: Read the file as lines, or read the whole thing, split into lines. Either way you get a list of lines. Then iterate through that list with a for loop and just use a python string copy to get the IP, since it always starts at a fixed location. So show some code and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the IP address seems to always be in the last column, so this should suffice:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        cols = line.split() # split line at whitespace
        ip = cols[-1] # get last column
        ip = ip.strip('[]') # remove brackets
        print(ip) # print the IP address
```

If you really need to use splicing, you can use `last_part = line[32:]` to get the part containing the domain names and IP addresses. Then you need to check if a bracket (or space) is in this part. If there isn't, print `last_part`, else use `.split()` and `.strip()` or `.index()` and splicing to get the part between the brackets and print it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
import re 

self.proxy_list = []
for line in open(file, "r+").readlines():
      pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\:\d{2,5})') `enter 
      self.proxy_list.append(pattern.search(line)[0])
```